# How to replace a substring between two strings at multiple places in a single line

Tags: .net, regex, pattern-matching

I want to replace the string between FFFFFF & EE9911 at multiple places like this

`FFFFFF first EE9911 second FFFFFF thrid EE9911 fourth`
into this

`FFFFFF <data> EE9911 second FFFFFF <data> EE9911 fourth`

Can you suggest any regex pattern?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I have tried these FFFFFF(.*)EE9911 , FFFFFF([^s]+)\s*?EE9911

Comment: Hi Rishika, welcome to SO. Always add your previous attempts to the question itself, it enriches the question showing that you already tried to find a solution by yourself and makes easier to help you. May I suggest you take a look at the help section about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: thanks @Dinei. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to match the string to be replaced in `.Net`

```
(?<=FFFFFF\s+).*?(?=\s+EE9911)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DFFFFFF%5Cs%2B%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%5Cs%2BEE9911%29&i=FFFFFF%20first%20EE9911%20second%20FFFFFF%20thrid%20EE9911%20fourth%20into%20this%0D%0A%0D%0AFFFFFF%20%3Cdata%3E%20EE9911%20second%20FFFFFF%20%3Cdata%3E%20EE9911%20fourth)

In C#,

```
var regx = new Regex(@"(?<=FFFFFF\s+).*?(?=\s+EE9911)");
Console.WriteLine(regx.Replace(text, @"<data>"));
```